# How to turn off display without turning off the keyboard blacklight?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, display, keyboard-backlight

I want the keyboard backlight to be on when the computer sleeps.
So I want to know how to turn the display off while the blacklight is on.
Or how to turn on the keyboard blacklight while the display is off.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn display backlight.

Turn backlight off:

```sh
echo 0 | sudo tee $(find /sys/devices -path '*backlight/brightness')
```

Turn backlight on:

```sh
cat $(find /sys/class -path '*backlight/max_brightness') | \
sudo tee $(find /sys/devices -path '*backlight/brightness')
```

### Explanation:

- Find `brightness` interface of your display:

`find /sys/devices -path '*backlight/brightness'`

- Set `brightness` of display to `0` with `sudo` privileges:

`cat 0 | sudo tee <display brightness>`

- Get `max_brightness` of display:

`cat $(find /sys/class -path '*backlight/max_brightness')`

- Set `brightness` of display to `max_brightness` with `sudo` privileges:

`cat <max_brightness> | sudo tee <display brightness>`

Comment: I like the technique of `find /sys/devices -path '*backlight/brightness'` don't recall seeing this trick before.

Comment: and if you need it    'xset led on' or 'xset led off'